# Seting up a relationship in Eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have 3 tables:

- projects
- jobs
- categories

Projects have jobs and jobs are assigned to categories. The jobs table contains a project ID and a category ID, that is, jobs are linked to both projects and categories. My quetion:

- How can I setup a relationship on project model to query projects given a category ID
- How can I setup a relationship on category model to query projects

[diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LpdLp.png)

Comment: You read the docs, and give it a try.

Comment: I did, but i couldn't achieve to query project records through jobs table. Would you give me an example or just a tip? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

### Got it!

Querying categories over the project model. Over this relation, **projects** can query all **category** records which their **jobs** assigned to.

```php
// In Project model class
public function categories()
{ 
    $relation = $this->hasManyThrough(
        Category::class,  // target model
        Job::class,       // intermediate model
        'project_id',     // column with project ID in jobs table
        'id',             // ID column in categories table
        'id',             // ID column in projects table
        'category_id'     // column with category ID in jobs table
    );

    // remove duplicates
    $relation->getQuery()->distinct();

    return $relation;
}
```

Querying projects over the category model. Over this relation, **categories** can query all **project** records of **jobs** which assigned to a given category.

```
// In Category model class
public function projects()
{
    $relation = $this->hasManyThrough(
        Project::class,     // target model
        ProjectJob::class,  // intermadiate model
        'category_id',      // column with category ID in jobs table
        'uuid',             // ID column in projects table
        'uuid',             // ID column in categories table
        'project_id'        // column with project ID in jobs table
    );

    // remove duplicates
    $relation->getQuery()->distinct();

    return $relation;
}
```